# substract value fetched from sql with user input & output it in to another column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to substract from dquantity value of aquantity.

aquantity is user input whereas dquantity is fetched from SQL database.

Output of the substraction I am expecting in rquantity:

```
<table border="1">

    <tr>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Material Description</th>
        <th>dQuantity</th>
        <th>Unit of Measure</th>
        <th>AQuantity</th>
        <th>RQuantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <?php
            while($SSTR=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$SSTR['dmaterial']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$SSTR['dmdescription']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$SSTR['dquantity']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$SSTR['duom']."</td>";
                echo '<td><input placeholder="Accepted Qty" name="aqty'.$SSTR['duserref'].'" type="number" min="0" max="'. $SSTR['dquantity'] .'" autofocus></td>';
                echo '<td><input placeholder="Return Qty" name="rqty'.$SSTR['duserref'].'" type="number" min="0" max="'. $SSTR['dquantity'] .'"></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>  
</table>
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I want to autocalculate Rquantity can it be achieved in PHP and how ?

Comment: nope you need js for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following code for your solution. In script please place following function to calcute rquantity.

```
function findReturnQty(id)
{
    document.getElementById("rq"+id).value = parseInt(document.getElementById("dq"+id).innerHTML) - parseInt(document.getElementById("aq"+id).value);
}
```

Please modify PHP code as following :

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Material</th>
    <th>Material Description</th>
    <th>dQuantity</th>
    <th>Unit of Measure</th>
    <th>AQuantity</th>
    <th>RQuantity</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php
    $no = 0;
    while($SSTR=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records))
    {
        $no++;
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$SSTR['dmaterial'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$SSTR['dmdescription'].'</td>';
        echo '<td id="dq' . $no . '">'.$SSTR['dquantity'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $SSTR['duom'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><input id="aq'. $no .'" placeholder="Accepted Qty" name="aqty'.$SSTR['duserref'].'" type="number" min="0" max="'. $SSTR['dquantity'] .'" autofocus onChange="findReturnQty(' . $no . ')" ></td>';
        echo '<td><input id="rq'. $no .'" placeholder="Return Qty" name="rqty'.$SSTR['duserref'].'" type="number" min="0" max="'. $SSTR['dquantity'] .'"></td>';
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Mukesh Thanks for the code I am getting error   Undefined variable: no

Comment: Hi Mukesh You are right I did not copied code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After testing this code I have post this answer. Copy above code and run it. Therer is not any issue. In this code '$no=0' indicate value assign to variable. May be you forget to include in your code.